# copy file with spaces in to hdfs

Tags: linux

I have a file with name DT2516%_date_cdfs 05-feb-2017.csv .I need to copy it into hdfs . I am using the following command.

Hadoop fs -put DT2516%_date_cdfs 05-feb-2017.csv /tmp/

Error:
put : Unexpected URISyntaxException

How do I copy such files?

Comment: Have you tried double-quote the file name. `hadoop fs -put "some file with space" /tmp/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
cat DT2516%_date_cdfs\ 05-feb-2017.csv | hdfs dfs -put - '/tmp/DT2516%_date_cdfs 05-feb-2017.csv'
```

[image]